# Not able to copy a file via script from local host to remote host

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

I am trying to write a script that can copy a file from local host to remote host. And then i want to execute that script from local host. But I am not able to copy. I googled and found the below code. But on executing that, it is asking for passphrase. Even if I press enter or give some value or handle that in script, I am not able to copy the file. Please suggest what can be wrong with this script?

```
#!/bin/bash
Node_ip="10.172.54.2"

IP=("$Node_ip")

in_ip=""

get_ip()  #Give the ip of current machine
{
        for i in `ifconfig | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | grep -v '^$'`
        do
        if [ $i = "eth0" ]
        then
                if ifconfig $i | grep addr: &> /dev/null
                then
                        in_ip="$(ifconfig $i | grep addr: | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d":" -f2)"
                        echo "IP is : $in_ip"
                fi
        fi
        done
}

SCP_PASSWORD="gauranga"

for ne in "${IP[@]}"
do
    get_ip      #in_ip now has ip of current shell
    expect -c "  
       spawn scp gaur@$in_ip:/home/gaur/work_automation/commands.sh root@$ne:/root/gauranga/
       expect yes/no { send yes; exp_continue }
       expect password: { send $SCP_PASSWORD}
       exit
    "
done
```

Comment: I dont know if this is the problem, but when I scp a file the password prompt is : "Password: " ?

Comment: ya, even though i am using expect for password, i am facing issues

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions here:

- remote machine is accessible from local one under IP `1.2.3.4`
- `1.2.3.4` has SSH up and running on open port 22
- you know the password of user `foobar` on `1.2.3.4`

To copy the script to foobar's home directory:

`scp /path/to/script.sh foobar@1.2.3.4:~/`

Adding executable permissions to the script and running it:

`ssh foobar@1.2.3.4 "chmod +x ~/script.sh"`

`ssh foobar@1.2.3.4 "~/script.sh"`

If you need to do this often/automatically, read up about [setting up SSH keypairs for a passwordless login](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/). And DO NOT store your password as plaintext in a script, as it presents a serious security risk - SSH keys were made just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to "hit enter" for your send commands:

```
expect -c << END_EXPECT  
   spawn scp gaur@$in_ip:/home/gaur/work_automation/commands.sh root@$ne:/root/gauranga/
   expect { 
       yes/no { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
       password: { send "$SCP_PASSWORD\r"}
   }
   expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

Comment: I did what you told but still it is asking for passphrase. When I hit enter, it is exiting without file transfer.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` after the `spawn` command to see what's going on.